# Is there a way to delete a dependent junction(s) point when we delete the target folder?

Tags: windows, ntfs, junction

The situation would be something like this:

Target directory: `Target`

Junction Points:

- `Jun1` → `Target`
- `Jun2` → `Target`

What is the best way to delete the junction points if I delete the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest way to deal with junction points, reparse points, and hard links is with a tool that adds context menu entries and a property page for dealing with them. It makes creating them, finding their targets, and deleting them very easy. Try [HardLinkShellExtension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have found Powershell useful for this. I had a similar issue with not being able to delete an orphaned OneDrive folder.
The user had connected to one drive and synched folder and then changed password and broke the link. Uninstalling OneDrive did not clear it.
This left orphaned empty folders behind that could not be deleted in Windows as it said something was holding it open.

Using Powershell, I tried the del command and had an error saying:
del : c:\Users\UserID\Folder_To_Delete\ is an NFTS juntion point. Use the Force parameter to delete or modify this object.

I then ran: del '.\Folder_To_Delete\' -Force
This removed the orphaned folder.